# Cannot re-render react-chartjs-2 component even after state change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, chart.js

I have a React code that I have a Doughnut react-chartjs-2 component that I want to configure during runtime, and convert it to base64.

First I create a ref within the constructor:

```
 this.chartRef = React.createRef();
```

I have a state with the default properties that I bound to my component in the renders return statement:

```
 this.state = {
      chartOptions: chartOptions,
    };


<Doughnut
      redraw
      data={this.state.chartOptions}
      ref={this.chartRef as any}
    />
```

I then modify the state during runtime and expect the component to re-render:

```
reateDoughnut() {
    let chartCopy = { ...this.state.chartOptions };
    chartCopy.datasets[0].data = [
      ...chartCopy.datasets[0].data,
      this.state.Detractors,
      this.state.Passives,
      this.state.Promoters
    ];
    this.setState({
      chartOptions: chartCopy,
    }, () => {
      const chart = this.chartRef.current;
      const img = (chart as any).toBase64Image();
      console.log(img); //same as before
    });
  }
```

No matter what I try, I always get the same base64 value of the initial settings to the component. At first, I though that the issue was deepclone of the object, and the state didnt realise that it got assigned a new value, hence the component didnt re-render. But even after forcing an update with

> this.forceUpdate();

and also:

> const chartCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.chartOptions)); // deep copy

Nothing happened. I also added a redraw property to the component but no luck. Any clues?